# Can I upgrade my version of Ubuntu from the terminal?

Tags: upgrade

I have the 32-bit Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and I am wondering if I could upgrade to 15 or 16 from the terminal. I tried to open the update manager through the GUI but it did not open.

I already entered the commands `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade`.

Comment: Its not a duplicate of that

Comment: Have you tried running `update-manager` from the terminal to see why it won't launch

Comment: I just did and it had me restart for the updates I downloaded. This is very interesting.

Answer (score 3):

The following terminal command will update your Ubuntu version to the next available release. Press `CTRL+ALT+T` to open a terminal window or use the Unity application browser and search for "Terminal".

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade  #Upgrade to newest version
do-release-upgrade         #Alias of above
do-release-upgrade -d      #Upgrade to the newest development version
```

[Source](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/installing-upgrading.html)

Answer (score 0):

I actually had to change some settings before I was able to upgrade. What I had to do was go into system settings>>software and updates>>updates tab. Then I set the parameter for notifications of a new version of ubuntu to "for any release". Then I was able to use the software updater to check for new versions. I am now upgrading to 15.10.