# Upgrade Ubuntu Studio 19.10 to 20.04

Tags: upgrade, ubuntu-studio

I have already updated my Ubuntu Studio 19.10 version, but when trying to upgrade to Ubuntu Studio 20.04 even by Ubuntu upgrader software or by Terminal it does nothing. On Terminal I receive the message to update all 19.10 components before upgrading to 20.04, even if I have just done that, via software or terminal through `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` or `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`. What can I do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I upgrade my version of Ubuntu from the terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/777378/can-i-upgrade-my-version-of-ubuntu-from-the-terminal)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release) 19.10 is End of Life since July 18.